# How to build numpy with conary recipe for x-86 CentOs

Tags: python, numpy, centos

i am getting error:

```
rbuild build packages numpy --no-recurse 
[Tue Apr 26 13:16:53 2011] Creating rMake build job for 1 items

Added Job 902
  numpy:source=rmake-repository.bericots.com@local:taf32-sandbox-1-devel/1-0.2
[13:17:23] Watching job 902            
[13:17:24] [902] Loading 1 out of 1: numpy:source
[13:17:26] [902] - State: Loaded         
[13:17:26] [902] - job troves set        
[13:17:27] [902] - State: Building              
[13:17:27] [902] - Building troves              
d all buildreqs: [TroveSpec('python2.4:runtime'), TroveSpec('python2.4:devel')]
[13:17:27] [902] - numpy:source{x86} - State: Queued
[13:17:27] [902] - numpy:source{x86} - Ready for dep resolution
[13:17:28] [902] - numpy:source{x86} - State: Resolving
[13:17:28] [902] - numpy:source{x86} - Resolving build requirements
[13:17:28] [902] - State: Failed                   
[13:17:28] [902] - Failed while building: Build job had failures:
   * numpy:source: Could not satisfy build requirements: python2.4:runtime=[], python2.4:devel=[]

902 numpy{x86} - Resolving - (Job Failed) ([h]elp)>
error: Job 902 has failures, not committing
error: Package build failed
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command $rbuild build packages numpy --no-recurse , should be executed at the level where the package is, not in Development/QA or Release Directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have all the dependencies. The [install page](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux) may help you.

Comment: I am not building this manually, but rather using rPATH's conary recipe. BTW i did resolve this, but thanks